# Infinite Lie algebra

Tags: soft-question, lie-groups, lie-algebras

It is well known fact that the finite dimensional Lie algebra will always be closed under commutation relation. But I have doubt about infinite Lie algebra. In some of the case it is closed under commutation relation and in other cases it not. Can we claim in general that infinite dimensional Lie algebra would not be closed under commutation ??

Comment: What do you mean by commutation relation?

Answer (score 2):

By definition, a vector space is a *Lie algebra*, if the Lie bracket is "closed under commutation relation", i.e., $[x,y]\in L$ for all $x,y\in L$, and satisfies skew-symmetry and the Jacobi identity. This holds for finite-dimensional and infinite-dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: Then please comment on infinite Lie algebra of [Manakov-Santini system given in this article](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10440-014-9909-9), section 2.1. See the commutator table with entry corresponding to $[\chi_{1}, \chi_{2}]$ which proves my claim. This entry should be $f_{1}(t)f_{2}^{\prime}(t)\frac{\partial}{\partial u}+yf_{1}(t)f_{3}^{\prime}(t)\frac{\partial}{\partial v}$, but author has taken it as zero.

Comment: Which claim of yours is proved ? $[\chi_1,\chi_2]=0\in L$ is "closed", because $0$ is always in the vector space. How did you compute $[\chi_1,\chi_2]$ ?

Comment: $[\chi_{1}, \chi_{2}]= \,f_{1}(t)\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(f_{2}(t)\frac{\partial}{\partial u}+yf_{3}(t)\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\right)-\left(f_{2}(t)\frac{\partial}{\partial u}+yf_{3}(t)\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\right)f_{1}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}=\,f_{1}(t)f_{2}(t)^{\prime}\frac{\partial}{\partial u}+yf_{1}(t)f_{3}(t)^{\prime}\frac{\partial}{\partial v}$

Comment: The vector obtained as result of commutation does not belong to Lie algebra of Manakov- Santini system.

Comment: It does belong to it if the result simplifies to zero (and this is what the authors think).

Comment: No way for simplification to zero. This would be zero only if $f_{1}(t)=0$ or $f_{2}(t)=f_{3}(t)=$constant, but this can not be allowed in general. Author too is admitting mistake but  not as such.

Comment: The best thing is to clarify this with the author, I think. What is his argument, that it is still correct ?